# sqlite 3.4 updating table with data from different table - changed with 3.3 - newbie question

Tags: join, update, sqlite

All of the other questions on this seem to be before 3.3 when sqlite added an update join feature? Newbie here, so I may even be getting the terminology wrong. I am trying to update the issbn field in table GULLfromLG (currently empty), with data from the issbn field in BIBinfo (field can be empty in a given record).

I am using SQLiteStudio. From looking through the documentation, sqlitetutorial, w3resource, and general web searches I believe the following should work. But it doesn't. The processing happens, is declared successful, but all the fields in GULLfromLG are empty. What am I missing?

```
    UPDATE GULLfromLG
   SET issbn = (
   select issbn
  FROM BIBinfo
 WHERE bibno = bibno)
```

I have also tried naming the fields with variations of
`GULLfromLG.issbn GULLfromLG.bibno BIBinfo.issbn BIBinfo.bibno`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll definitely need to use **aliases** to distinguish which instance of `bibno` you're referring to in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to gove sqllite the chance to know which column from which table you mean

```
UPDATE GULLfromLG
   SET issbn = (
   SELECT issbn
  FROM BIBinfo
 WHERE bibno = GULLfromLG.bibno)
[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c6687/1)
```